# Generate SmartWatch icons

Tags: sony, sony-smartwatch

Does Sony have something for their SmartWatch icons similar to below link?

http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no tool to generate Icons for smartwatch but we do have guidelines to help developers  generate proper icons.

You can find more info here: http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/tool-guides/download-the-new-smart-extension-sdk-and-create-smart-extras-apps/

**Update:** The Sony Smartwatch design guidelines are available in Sony Add-on Documentation kit or directly here: http://dl-developer.sonymobile.com/documentation/other/SmartWatch_products_2.pdf